# A library of 2D Shapes with functions for their intersections

Tags: c++, game, functional-programming, mathematics, collision

The goal was as much code reuse as I could get. Shooting for a pure-function-y style.

Would love any feedback on general architecture, adherence to standard practice and usability - as well as ideas for improving which I may not have considered.

Would also love advice for making these shapes more generic, in order that it'd be easier to iterate over, say, a vector containing different shapes.

The olcPixelGameEngine is a wonderful single-header solution for printing to the screen and accepting user input. It can be found at https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/olcPixelGameEngine.

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "olcPixelGameEngine.h"

// std::vector of Vector2Ds
#define Points std::vector<olc::vf2d>

inline bool operator==(const olc::vf2d& v1, const olc::vf2d& v2) { return v1.x == v2.x && v1.y == v2.y; }
inline bool operator!=(const olc::vf2d& v1, const olc::vf2d& v2) { return !(v1 == v2); }


///////////////////////////////////////////////// S H A P E S ///////////////////////////////////////////////


struct Line
{
    olc::vf2d p1;
    olc::vf2d p2;
};

struct Segment
{
    olc::vf2d p1;
    olc::vf2d p2;

    Line AsLine() const { return Line{ p1, p2 }; }
};

inline bool operator==(const Segment& s1, const Segment& s2) { return { s1.p1 == s2.p1 && s1.p2 == s2.p2 }; }
inline bool operator!=(const Segment& s1, const Segment& s2) { return !(s1 == s2); }

struct Ray
{
    olc::vf2d pos;
    olc::vf2d dir;
    Line AsLine() const { return Line{ pos, dir }; }
    Segment AsSegment() const { return Segment{ pos, (dir - pos) * 1000 }; }
};

struct Circle
{
    olc::vf2d pos;
    float radius;
};

struct Polygon
{
    Points points;
    olc::vf2d PointAfter(int i) const
    {
        return (i < points.size() - 1) ? points[i + 1] : points[0];
    }
};

// Axis-aligned Bounding Box
struct RectAABB
{
    olc::vf2d pos;
    olc::vf2d size;
    Polygon AsPolygon() const
    {
        return  Polygon{
            Points{
                pos,
                {pos.x + size.x, pos.y},
                pos + size,
                {pos.x, pos.y + size.y}
            }
        };
    }
};


/////////////////////////////////////////////// U T I L I T Y //////////////////////////////////////////////

template <typename T>
bool IsBetween(T f, T low, T high)
{
    return f > low && f < high;
}

// Returns whether an intersection is within the bounds of a line segment
bool IsLegalSegment(const olc::vf2d& i, const Segment& s)
{
    olc::vf2d check = {
        (i.x - s.p1.x) / (s.p2.x - s.p1.x),
        (i.y - s.p1.y) / (s.p2.y - s.p1.y)
    };

    return (IsBetween(check.x, 0.0f, 1.0f) || IsBetween(check.y, 0.0f, 1.0f));
}

// used in calculations
struct StandardForm
{
    float A, B, C;
};

// Returns the standard form of a line
StandardForm GetStandardForm(const Line& l)
{
    float A = l.p2.y - l.p1.y;
    float B = l.p1.x - l.p2.x;
    float C = A * l.p1.x + B * l.p1.y;
    return { A, B, C };
}

// Takes a list of intersections and returns a vector containing those which are
// within the bounds of either one or two line segments. Used frequently in other functions.
const Segment NULL_SEG = { {0.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f} };
Points SegmentIntersections(Points intersections, const Segment& seg1, const Segment& seg2 = NULL_SEG)
{
    Points result(0);
    if (intersections.size() > 0)
        for (olc::vf2d p : intersections)
        {
            if (IsLegalSegment(p, seg1))
            {
                if (seg2 == NULL_SEG)
                {
                    result.push_back(p);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (IsLegalSegment(p, seg2))
                        result.push_back(p);
                }
            }
        }

    return result;
}

// The equation for the intersection between a circle and a line in standard form. 
// Don't forget to translate to the origin before and after using!
Points CircleVsStandardLine(const Circle& c, const StandardForm& s)
{
    // copied and pasted - could put in seperate function
    float fA2byB2 = (s.A * s.A) + (s.B * s.B);
    if (fA2byB2 == 0) return Points(0);

    float fSqrt = (c.radius * c.radius) * (fA2byB2) - (s.C * s.C);
    if (fSqrt == 0) return Points(0);

    return Points{
        olc::vf2d{
            ((s.A * s.C) + s.B * sqrt(fSqrt)) / fA2byB2,
            ((s.B * s.C) - s.A * sqrt(fSqrt)) / fA2byB2
        } + c.pos,  // translate back

        olc::vf2d{
            ((s.A * s.C) - s.B * sqrt(fSqrt)) / fA2byB2,
            ((s.B * s.C) + s.A * sqrt(fSqrt)) / fA2byB2
        } + c.pos
    };
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////// I N T E R S E C T I O N S ///////////////////////////////////////////////


inline bool PointInCircle(const olc::vf2d& p, const Circle& c)
{
    return (c.pos - p).mag() < c.radius;
}

inline bool PointInRect(const olc::vf2d& p, const RectAABB& r)
{
    return (
        p.x > r.pos.x &&
        p.y > r.pos.y &&
        p.x < r.pos.x + r.size.x &&
        p.y < r.pos.y + r.size.y);
}


//////////////////////// L I N E   V S . ////////////////////////////


inline Points LineVsLine(const Line& l1, const Line& l2)
{
    StandardForm s1 = GetStandardForm(l1);
    StandardForm s2 = GetStandardForm(l2);
    
    float fDenom = s1.A * s2.B - s2.A * s1.B;
    if (fDenom == 0) return Points(0);

    return Points{ 
        olc::vf2d{
            (s2.B * s1.C - s1.B * s2.C) / fDenom,
            (s2.C * s1.A - s1.C * s2.A) / fDenom
        }
    };
}

inline Points LineVsSegment(const Line& l, const Segment& s)
{
    return SegmentIntersections(LineVsLine(l, s.AsLine()), s);
}

inline Points LineVsRay(const Line& l, const Ray& r)
{
    return SegmentIntersections(LineVsLine(l, r.AsLine()), r.AsSegment());
}

inline Points LineVsCircle(const Line& l, const Circle& c)
{
    Line t = {
        l.p1 - c.pos,
        l.p2 - c.pos };

    Points intersections = CircleVsStandardLine(c, GetStandardForm(t));
    for (olc::vf2d p : intersections)
        p += c.pos;

    return intersections;
}

inline Points LineVsPolygon(const Line& l, const Polygon& p)
{
    Points result;
    for (int i = 0; i < p.points.size(); i++)
    {
        Points intersections = LineVsSegment(l, Segment{ p.points[i], p.PointAfter(i) });
        result.insert(result.begin(), intersections.begin(), intersections.end());
    }
    return result;
}

inline Points LineVsRectAABB(const Line& l, const RectAABB& r)
{
    return LineVsPolygon(l, r.AsPolygon());
}


//////////////////////// S E G M E N T   V S . ////////////////////////////


inline Points SegmentVsSegment(const Segment& s1, const Segment& s2)
{
    return SegmentIntersections(LineVsLine(s1.AsLine(), s2.AsLine()), s1, s2);
}

inline Points SegmentVsRay(const Segment& s, const Ray& r)
{
    return SegmentIntersections(LineVsLine(s.AsLine(), r.AsLine()), s, r.AsSegment());
}

inline Points SegmentVsCircle(const Segment& s, const Circle& c)
{
    return SegmentIntersections(LineVsCircle(s.AsLine(), c), s);
}

inline Points SegmentVsPolygon(const Segment& s, const Polygon& p)
{
    Points result;
    for (int i = 0; i < p.points.size(); i++)
    {
        Points intersections = SegmentVsSegment(s, Segment{ p.points[i], p.PointAfter(i) });
        result.insert(result.begin(), intersections.begin(), intersections.end());
    }
    return result;
}

inline Points SegmentVsRectAABB(const Segment& s, const RectAABB& r)
{
    return SegmentVsPolygon(s, r.AsPolygon());
}


/////////////////////////////// R A Y   V S . ////////////////////////////////////


inline Points RayVsRay(const Ray& r1, const Ray& r2)
{
    return SegmentIntersections(LineVsLine(r1.AsLine(), r2.AsLine()), r1.AsSegment(), r2.AsSegment());
}


inline Points RayVsCircle(const Ray& r, const Circle& c)
{
    return SegmentIntersections(SegmentVsCircle(r.AsSegment(), c), r.AsSegment());
}

inline Points RayVsPolygon(const Ray& r, const Polygon& p)
{
    Points result;
    for (int i = 0; i < p.points.size(); i++)
    {
        Points intersections = SegmentVsRay(Segment{ p.points[i], p.PointAfter(i) }, r);
        result.insert(result.begin(), intersections.begin(), intersections.end());
    }
    return result;
}

inline Points RayVsRectAABB(const Ray& r, const RectAABB& rect)
{
    return RayVsPolygon(r, rect.AsPolygon());
}


///////////////////////////// C I R C L E   V S . //////////////////////////////////


inline Points CircleVsCircle(const Circle& c1, const Circle& c2)
{
    olc::vf2d p1 = c1.pos - c1.pos;
    olc::vf2d p2 = c2.pos - c1.pos;
    float r1 = c1.radius;
    float r2 = c2.radius;

    StandardForm LineBetween = {
        2 * (p2.x - p1.x),
        2 * (p2.y - p1.y),
        (r1 * r1) - (p1.x * p1.x) - (p1.y * p1.y) - (r2 * r2) + (p2.x * p2.x) + (p2.y * p2.y)
    };

    Points intersections = CircleVsStandardLine(c1, LineBetween);
    for (olc::vf2d p : intersections)
        p += c1.pos;

    return intersections;
}

inline Points CircleVsPolygon(const Circle& c, const Polygon& p)
{
    Points result;
    for (int i = 0; i < p.points.size(); i++)
    {
        Points intersections = SegmentVsCircle(Segment{ p.points[i], p.PointAfter(i) }, c);
        result.insert(result.begin(), intersections.begin(), intersections.end());
    }
    return result;
}

inline Points CircleVsRectAABB(const Circle& c, const RectAABB& r)
{
    return CircleVsPolygon(c, r.AsPolygon());
}


//////////////////////////////// P O L Y G O N   V S . ////////////////////////////////////


inline Points PolygonVsPolygon(const Polygon& p1, const Polygon& p2)
{
    Points result;
    for (int i = 0; i < p1.points.size(); i++)
    {
        Points intersections = SegmentVsPolygon(Segment{ p1.points[i], p1.PointAfter(i) }, p2);
        result.insert(result.begin(), intersections.begin(), intersections.end());
    }
    return result;
}

inline Points PolygonVsRectAABB(const Polygon& p1, const RectAABB& r)
{
    return PolygonVsPolygon(p1, r.AsPolygon());
}


//////////////////////////////// R E C T   A A B B   V S . ///////////////////////////////////


inline Points RectAABBVsRectAABB(const RectAABB& r1, const RectAABB& r2)
{
    return PolygonVsPolygon(r1.AsPolygon(), r2.AsPolygon());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Enable compiler warnings and fix all of them

Trying to compile your code results in several warnings from the compiler (I'm using GCC 10.2 with `-Wall -W -pedantic -std=c++17`). In particular:

- Narrowing conversion from `double` to `float` due to the use of `sqrt()` in `CircleVsStandardLine()`. You should use [`std::sqrt()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) here, which is the C++ version of C's [`sqrt()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sqrt) which automatically returns the right precision depending on the argument.
- Comparison between signed and unsigned integers. This is mainly when declaring `int i` as an array index. I recommend using `size_t` for array indices where possible.

## Avoid using lots of different names for functions that do the same thing

You have created separate types for lines, rays and segments. This is quite nice, because even if they are all defined by two points and behave very similarly, it avoids errors where you accidentily treat a segment as a line or vice versa.

However, you missed a big opportunity. You wrote lots of functions with names like `LineVsLine()`, `LineVsSegment()`, when you could have written overloads of a function named `Intersection()`:

```
inline Point Intersection(const Line &l1, const Line &l2) {...}
inline Points Intersection(const Line &l, const Segment &s) {...}
...
inline Points Intersection(const RectAABB &r1, const RectAABB &r2) {...}
```

The advantage of the above is that you no longer have to remember the name of the function when you want to get the intersection of two objects, you just write `auto result = Intersection(object1, object2)`. This represents the programmer's intent much better. Let the compiler worry about the types.

## Make use of value initialization

I noticed the following lines:

```
const Segment NULL_SEG = { {0.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f} };
Points SegmentIntersections(Points intersections, const Segment& seg1, const Segment& seg2 = NULL_SEG)
{
    ...
```

First, you don't need to explicitly initialize all members of `NULL_SEG`, you can write the following which will perform [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), and will effectively set all members to zero in this case:

```
const Segment NULL_SEG = {};
```

But, if you can just write `{}`, there is no reason any more to abbreviate this to a constant named `NULL_SEG`. Instead you can do this:

```
Points SegmentIntersections(Points intersections, const Segment& seg1, const Segment& seg2 = {})
{
    ...
```

If you call `SegmentIntersections()` without specifying `seg2`, it will create a temporary `Segment` which is value-initialized. To be able to completely get rid of `NULL_SEG`, you have to replace:

```
if (seg2 == NULL_SEG)
```

with:

```
if (seg2 == Segment{})
```

## Use member functions where appropriate

There are several out-of-class functions that might be better as a class member function. For example, consider making `PointInCircle()` a member function of `Circle`:

```
struct Circle
{
    olc::vf2d pos;
    float radius;

    bool Contains(const Point &p) const
    {
        return (c.pos - p).mag() < c.radius;
    }
};
```

And `GetStandardForm()` might be written as a member function of `Line`.

Comment: What a generous, helpful critique. Thank you so much for your time and your advice! This is all really good stuff. This has helped me a lot, thank you!

Comment: @TyMiles You're welcome! If you find the answer useful, consider marking it as the accepted answer. If someone else comes later and gives an even better answer, you can always change which answer is the accepted one.